# CorePlot ScatterPlot labelingPolicy

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am using CorePlot to plot average prices over few months.
This is what I am trying to achieve 
[image: graph]

I have been able to produce this
[image: simulator]

So clearly graph does not look plotted correctly.

Heres the code I am using in my viewController to set up the graph and plot it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
NSDictionary *jsonDataDictionary;
// Can be done async with loading timers
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                @"http://greyloft.com/analytics/query.php?project=PARC%20VISTA&area=1200&months=5"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

if (urlData) {
    NSError *error=nil;
    jsonDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                            error:&error];
    // We receive the order of the months in reverse order in the json i.e. most recent first.
    // e.g. Feb-15, Jan-15, Dec-14 and so on
    // We need to show plotting in reverse order on x axis effectively needing to reverse the array.
    NSArray *reverseAvgRentals = [[jsonDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"average"];
    _averageRentals = [[reverseAvgRentals reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    _transactions = [[jsonDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"transactions"];

    _months = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _rentals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *rental in _averageRentals) {
        [_months addObject:[rental objectForKey:@"month"]];
        [_rentals addObject:[rental objectForKey:@"average"]];
    }
    // KVC to find min/max in an array
    _minRental = _maxRental = 0;
    _minRental = [[_rentals valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"] intValue];
    _maxRental = [[_rentals valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
}}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [_months count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {
        // Simply return index as we want to return number for each month
        num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index+1];
    } else {
        num = [[_averageRentals objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"average"];
    }
    return num;
}

    -(void)initPlot {
    [self configureHost];
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];
}

-(void)configureHost {
    self.graphHostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphContainerView.bounds];
    self.graphHostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.graphContainerView addSubview:self.graphHostView];
}

-(void)configureGraph {
    // Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphHostView.bounds];
    [graph applyTheme:nil];
    self.graphHostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:30.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:30.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingTop:10.0f];
}

-(void)configurePlots {
    // Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.graphHostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    // 2 - Create the plot
    CPTScatterPlot *rentPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    rentPlot.dataSource = self;
    rentPlot.identifier = @"Rent";
    [graph addPlot:rentPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    // 3 - Set up plot space
    CGFloat xMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat xMax = [_months count];
    CGFloat yMin = _minRental;
    CGFloat yMax = _maxRental;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMin)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax)];

    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlotSpaces]];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.4)];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(3.0)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

    // 4 - Create styles and symbols
    //CPTColor *orangeColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:239.0f green:92.0f blue:94.0f alpha:1.0f];
    CPTColor *orangeColor = [CPTColor orangeColor];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [rentPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5f;
    lineStyle.lineColor = orangeColor;
    rentPlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5f;
    symbolLineStyle.lineColor = orangeColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:248.0f
                                                                   green:244.0f
                                                                    blue:251.0f
                                                                   alpha:1.0f]];
    symbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;
    symbol.size = CGSizeMake(11.0f, 11.0f);
    rentPlot.plotSymbol = symbol;
}

-(void)configureAxes {
    // 1 - Create styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.0f;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor grayColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Ubuntu-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 14.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];

    // 2 - Get axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.graphHostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;

    // 3 - Configure x-axis
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.0);
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
    x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 6;
    x.labelOffset = 50.0f;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
    x.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
    NSMutableSet *xLabelSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[_months count]];
    NSMutableSet *xLocationSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[_months count]];

    int location = 0;
    for (NSString *month in _months) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:month textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(location++);
        [xLabelSet addObject:label];
        [xLocationSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:location]];
    }
    x.axisLabels = xLabelSet;
    x.majorTickLocations = xLocationSet;

    // 4 - Configure y-axis
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(-0.1);
    y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 6;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
    y.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
}
```

I am not getting the concept of how CorePlot will take the data provided and turn it into the required set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Plot ranges take a `location` and `length` like `NSRange`. You can use the min value for the `location` and `max - min` for the `length`.

Comment: The question isn't clear. What do you mean by "the required set"?

Comment: Thanks Eric for the feedback. What I meant is how do I extrapolate the min,max value say for Y-axis I need the labels shuold start from 1500 and end at 4000 (all values are between 3000 and 4000). I understand you have mentioned in the comment above to use min value for location and max-min for length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my comment above, plot ranges take a `location` and `length` like `NSRange`. You can use the min value for the location and `max - min` for the length.

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(yMin)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(yMax - yMin)];
```

For your example of a range covering 1,500 to 4,000, use 1,500 for the location and 2,500 (4,000 - 1,500) for the length.

Comment: ok ... that helped ... however I am not not able to see x-axis at all ... the only thing I have changed is CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation: to suggested values. See screenshot here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNycg3hp-CmRl9OQ3ZLa21pTTg/view?usp=sharing ... I am using y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic; I know theres a little bit of magic behind the scenes where it determines the y-labels which its doing great. However how is this affecting x-axis labels?

Comment: The crossing point of the axes is determined by the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal`. You've got the x-axis set to cross the y-axis at y = 0. Either change that to `yMin` or use the `axisConstraints` to position the axis instead.

Comment: Ok I was able to use the constraint as x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:35.0f]; and it moved the x-axis down. I have two more things pending now. 1. Need to figure out how to start the majorgridline from start of Y-Axis line so it does not cross the labels and 2. How to add custom S$ before the Y-Axis labels.

Comment: 1. The constraint offset is measured from the edge of the plot area, which also determines the extent of the grid lines. I'm having trouble picturing what you want, but you need to adjust the constraint offset and the padding. 2. Use the `labelFormatter`. Set up an `NSNumberFormatter` with the desired prefix string and use that to format the labels.

Comment: For 1. Using the constraints will affect the position of the labels as well right? I want the labels and the y-axis line (hidden) to stay where they are and only the majorgridlines to start from a little offset. This is what I am looking for - http://bit.ly/1akxiCT and this is what I have been able to achieve so far - http://bit.ly/1aUXyow ... Hope its clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: 2. For NumberFormatter, I tried using     NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadAfterPrefix];
    [formatter setPaddingCharacter:@"S$"];
    y.labelFormatter = formatter;
 But it still does not prepend the characters. What am I missing here?

Comment: 2. You want to use the `positivePrefix` and/or `negativePrefix`, not the padding.

Comment: 1. Do you care if the plot can scroll over the labels? If so, you need to adjust the left padding. Otherwise, you can use the `gridLinesRange` to shorten the grid lines.

Comment: Eric - You awesome ... or you awesome bro! ... That was perfect. Thanks a bunch! Sorry for extending the comment section but this is the last comment.